# Where to define global constants in RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

I'd like to define global constants in RubyMotion. What is the best way to declare global constants?

If it's Rails, put global constants in `config/initializers/constants.rb` is common way, I think. Any alternative place in RubyMotion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a specific place to put them. I'd recommend creating a config folder and dropping your `constants.rb` file into that. Then, any constants you define in that file should be available to your classes.

```
# /app/config/constants.rb
THIS_IS_MY_CONSTANT = "Yep"

# /app/app_delegate.rb
class AppDelegate
  def application(app, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: opt)
    puts THIS_IS_MY_CONSTANT # => "Yep"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Jamon. I created a config folder outside app directory and then added

`app.files << Dir.glob("./config/*.rb")`

to my Rakefile.